# How to make a colour clicker using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, mouse, color

How can AppleScript be used to make the mouse cursor search for a colour on the screen and click on it when found and return to its starting position after?

How to make a script that can do this process:

1. define a colour by selecting it from a screenshot
2. search on that defined colour and click it then return back to starting position

Comment: This task is likely too technical for Ask Different to really help you with. You will probably attract better answers over at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Like "Digital Color Maker" the System Os X app ?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: AppleScript questions are on-topic here, so I don't see a problem with having this question on AskDifferent. If you can add some details about what you have tried so far, this would be great. Also, if you want us to move the question to StackOverflow if you don't get good answers here, just flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org) to implement your task rather than AppleScript:

> Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.